# AWS Amplify apps with AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js

I'm having my `Next.js` app deployed on AWS Amplify, and within my app I need to publish a message to an SQS queue. Locally I can work with the `aws-sdk` using environment variables ( `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`), but Amplify prevents me from adding these vars so the application failed.

> Environment variables cannot start with the reserved prefix "AWS".

So the question is what should be the preferred approach in my case? I don't want to specify the credentials directly in code.

Here is the piece of code:

```js
const sqsClient = new SQSClient( );
const command = new SendMessageCommand({
  QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL,
  MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body),
});
await sqsClient.send(command);
```

Error message:

```
Error SQS CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
```